# vba Run-Time error '1004'- Method 'Range' of object '_global' failed

Tags: excel, vba

Below code is working to copy data from B2 to B114 cell of column B of excel sheet.

When adding B117 cell in range to copy then "Run-Time error '1004'- Method 'Range' of object '_global' failed error is occurring.

B117 is counted 53rd cell to copy from column B, as some of the cells are skipped by me which i don't want to copy.

If i am removing B117 cell from range then this code works well without any error, Anybody know what mistake I'm making?

I want to add B117, B118, B119 and more cells in range.

```
Sub AddEntry()
Range("B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B9, B10, B11, B12, B13, B14, B15, B16, B17, B18, B19, B20, B21, B22, B23, B24, B25, B26, B27, B28, B31, B32, B34, B35, B36, B37, B38, B48, B50, B51, B52, B57, B64, B68, B72, B76, B78, B85, B92, B96, B100, B104, B108, B112, B114, B117").Copy
Sheets("Horizontal_Table").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False End Sub
```

Comment: Try and identify the value of `B117`. It might be that it has **Special Characters** which are causing the problem. Also, as the question is related to VBA, you must add VBA tag to your question

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to clarify your problem description. That should help you getting more answers. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And take the tour!

Comment: B117 having same texts like B2,B3,B4

Comment: See [VBA range - 255 character limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45558842/vba-range-255-character-limit)

Comment: checked but not working

Comment: @AmirTamboli the point being that you'll need to use `Union` - you're going over the 255 character limit.

Answer (score 0):

### The **RANGE** Approach

Hi, done some investigating and came up with this:

```
Option Explicit
'QuestionTitle: vba Run-Time error '1004'- Method 'Range' of object '_global' failed
'QuestionLink: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52220889/vba-run-time-error-1004-method-range-of-object-global-failed/52226045
Sub AddEntry()
'Variables
    'Use constants for names:
    Const cwsV As String = "Vertical_Table"
    Const cwsH As String = "Horizontal_Table"
    'Workbooks, worksheets, ranges etc.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsV As Worksheet
    Dim wsH As Worksheet
    Dim raV As Range
    'A range can be declared by a string, so use string variables:
    Dim strV1 As String
    Dim strRight As String
'Assign
    Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsV = wb.Worksheets(cwsV)
    Set wsH = wb.Worksheets(cwsH)
'Program
'-- You can safely delete this BEGIN -------------------------------------------
'Solution1:
    'I'm guessing that the maximum characters used for declaring a range is 255.
    'You have used all 255 characters, but if you remove the spaces you have
    'used only 204. So you get additional 51 characters for about 10 entries.
'---------------------------------------
'    strV1 = "B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,B10,B11," & _
'      "B12,B13,B14,B15,B16,B17,B18,B19,B20,B21," & _
'      "B22,B23,B24,B25,B26,B27,B28,B31,B32,B34," & _
'      "B35,B36,B37,B38,B48,B50,B51,B52,B57,B64," & _
'      "B68,B72,B76,B78,B85,B92,B96,B100,B104,B108," & _
'      "B112,B114"
'    Set raV = wsV.Range(strV1)
'    Debug.Print strV1 'B2,B3,B4...,B114 - 204 characters
'    Debug.Print raV.Address '$B$2,$B$3,$B$4...,$B$78 - Wrong!?
'    'Obviously the address of a range cannot exceed 255 characters, too. But
'    'the program functions correctly!?
'    GoTo lblCopy
'---------------------------------------
'Solution2:
'    'Shorten the string of ranges
'    strV1 = "B2:B28,B31:B32,B34:B38,B48,B50:B52,B57,B64, " & _
'      "B68,B72,B76,B78,B85,B92,B96,B100,B104,B108,B112,B114"
'    Set raV = wsV.Range(strV1) '$B$2:$B$28,$B$31:$B$32...,$B$114 - 141 chars.
'    Debug.Print strV1 'B2:B28,B31:B32...B114 - 96 Characters
'    Debug.Print raV.Address
'    GoTo lblCopy
'---------------------------------------
'Solution3:
    'Introduce another new string variable and use the union function
    'The union function is automatically shortening the string range so this is
    'what we are going to use for the entries so far:
'-- You can safely delete this END ---------------------------------------------
    strV1 = "$B$2:$B$28,$B$31:$B$32,$B$34:$B$38,$B$48,$B$50:$B$52,$B$57,$B$64,"
    strV1 = strV1 & "$B$68,$B$72,$B$76,$B$78,$B$85,$B$92,$B$96,$B$100,$B$104,"
    strV1 = strV1 & "$B$108,$B$112,$B$114"
'Input New Entries Here:(you don't have to use the $ signs)
'-------------------
    strRight = "$B$117"
'-------------------
    If Len(strV1) > 255 Or Len(strRight) > 255 Then
        MsgBox "To many characters for range declaration. Do something!!!"
        GoTo ProgramEnd
    End If
        Set raV = Application.Union(wsV.Range(strV1), wsV.Range(strRight))
'The next four lines are wrong because the program has already failed.
'    If Len(raV.Address) > 255 Then
'        MsgBox "To many characters for range address. Do something!!!"
'        GoTo ProgramEnd
'    End If
'    Debug.Print strV1 '$B$2:$B$28,$B$31:B$32...B114 - 141 characters
'    Debug.Print strRight '$B$117 - 6 characters
'    Debug.Print raV.Address '$B$2:$B$28,$B$31:$B$32...$B$114,$B$117 - 147 chars.
lblCopy:
    raV.Copy
    wsH.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
ProgramEnd:
End Sub
```

Hope this helps you. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

### It's always ARRAYS

Hi again
A much better approach is of course using **arrays**. You read some data, copy it to an array, make some calculations and **BAMMM!**, in an instant the array is written to the range. You gotta try this one.

```
Option Explicit
'QuestionTitle: vba Run-Time error '1004'- Method 'Range' of object '_global' failed
'QuestionLink: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52220889/vba-run-time-error-1004-method-range-of-object-global-failed/52226045
Sub AddEntryArray()
'Variables
On Error GoTo VariablesErr
    'Use constants for names:
    Const cwsV As String = "Vertical_Table"
    Const cwsH As String = "Horizontal_Table"
    'Use constants for separators
    Const cSep As String = ","
    'Workbooks, worksheets, ranges etc.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsV As Worksheet
    Dim wsH As Worksheet
    Dim raC As Range
    Dim raR As Range
    Dim arrV As Variant
    Dim i1 As Integer
    Dim iF1 As Integer
    'A range can be declared by a string, so use string variables:
    Dim strV As String
    Dim strRight As String
    Dim strLeft As String
'Assign
On Error GoTo AssignErr
    Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsV = wb.Worksheets(cwsV)
    Set wsH = wb.Worksheets(cwsH)
    'New Entries here, you can put in spaces or $ signs but every entry has to
    'be a CELL range. You can't use B2:B4.
    strV = "B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,B10,B11,"
    strV = strV & "B12,B13,B14,B15,B16,B17,B18,B19,B20,B21,"
    strV = strV & "B22,B23,B24,B25,B26,B27,B28,B31,B32,B34,"
    strV = strV & "B35,B36,B37,B38,B48,B50,B51,B52,B57,B64,"
    strV = strV & "B68,B72,B76,B78,B85,B92,B96,B100,B104,B108,"
    strV = strV & "B112,B114"
    strV = strV & ""
    strV = strV & ""
    strV = strV & ""
'Program
On Error GoTo ProgramErr
    strRight = strV
    'Count number of cSeps (Commas in this case)
    Do Until InStr(1, strRight, cSep) = 0
        i1 = i1 + 1 'cSep found
        strRight = Right(strRight, Len(strRight) - InStr(1, strRight, cSep))
    Loop
    'There is one last entry after the last cSep therefore: i1 + 1 as UBound
    ReDim arrV(1 To 1, 1 To i1 + 1) As Variant
    strRight = strV
'Remarks: When using arrays they are usually two dimensional: rows & columns.
  'The first dimension representing the rows (fields, records...) is usually
  'used for the records, so without a second thought, LBound or UBound are used
  'with one argument only (Name of the array) e.g. LBound(arrV). But these
  'functions have a second argument namely the dimension which is by default or
  'if omitted equal to 1. So if you want to address the number of columns, you
  'have to use the second argument: LBound(arrV,2) or UBound(arrv,2).
    'Write the values of ranges to an array (the 2 stands for the 2nd dimension)
On Error GoTo ForNextErr
    For iF1 = LBound(arrV, 2) To UBound(arrV, 2)
        Select Case iF1
          Case Is < UBound(arrV, 2)
            'The left part is one range which is written to the array.
            strLeft = Trim(Left(strRight, InStr(1, strRight, cSep) - 1))
            arrV(1, iF1) = wsV.Range(strLeft).Value
'            Debug.Print iF1 & " - " & arrV(1, iF1)
            'The right part is what is left of the string and is processed again
            'in the next case of iF1
            strRight = Trim(Right(strRight, Len(strRight) - _
              InStr(1, strRight, cSep)))
          Case Else 'arrived at the last range, there is no cSep left
            arrV(1, iF1) = wsV.Range(strRight).Value
'            Debug.Print iF1 & " - " & arrV(1, iF1)
        End Select
    Next iF1
'Remarks: Above in the ForNext loop the Trim function isn't even needed. Looks
  'like Range trims the range values itself.
    'Determine the target range
    Set raC = wsH.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
'Remarks: raC is only the target cell, and we could loop now through the array
  'and write cell by cell to the target worksheet. But if we 'd know the range
  'we could write the array much faster to the range directly: range = array.
    'Determine target range
On Error GoTo TargetRangeErr
    Set raR = wsH.Range(Cells(raC.Row, raC.Column).Address & ":" & _
      Cells(raC.Row, raC.Column + i1).Address)
    'Write from array to worksheet (target range)
    raR = arrV
    GoTo ProgramEnd
VariablesErr:
    MsgBox "Something's wrong in Variables."
    GoTo ProgramEnd
AssignErr:
    MsgBox "Something's wrong in Assigning."
    GoTo ProgramEnd
ProgramErr:
    MsgBox "Something's wrong in Program."
    GoTo ProgramEnd
ForNextErr:
    MsgBox "Something's wrong in the ForNext loop."
    GoTo ProgramEnd
TargetRangeErr:
    MsgBox "Something's wrong with determining the target range."
    GoTo ProgramEnd
ProgramEnd:
End Sub
```

I like this one much better. Regards.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works.. used solution no 2.. excellent.